# Proper display of confidence interval in R using ggplot

Tags: r, graph, ggplot2

I'm trying to make a plot that will represent 2 measurements(prr and ebgm) for different adverse reactions of different drugs grouped by age category like so:

```
library(ggplot2)
strata <- factor(c("Neonates", "Infants", "Children", "Adolescents", "Pediatrics"), levels=c("Neonates", "Infants", "Children", "Adolescents", "Pediatrics"), order=T)
Data  <- data.frame(
                strata = sample(strata, 200, replace=T),
                drug=sample(c("ibuprofen", "clarithromycin", "fluticasone"), 200, replace=T), #20 de medicamente
                reaction=sample(c("Liver Injury", "Sepsis", "Acute renal failure", "Anaphylaxis"), 200, replace=T),
                measurement=sample(c("prr", "EBGM"), 200, replace=T),
                value_measurement=sample(runif(16), 200, replace=T),
                lower_CI=sample(runif(6), 200, replace=T),
                upper_CI=sample(runif(5), 200, replace=T)
                )

g <- ggplot(Data, aes(x=strata, y=value_measurement, fill=measurement, group=measurement))+
    geom_histogram(stat="identity", position="dodge")+
    facet_wrap(~reaction)+
    geom_errorbar(aes(x=strata, ymax=upper_CI, ymin=lower_CI), position="dodge", stat="identity")

ggsave(file="meh.png", plot=g)
```

The upper and lower CI are the confidence interval limit of the measurement. Given that I for each measurement I have a confidence interval I want the proper histogram to have the corresponding confidence interval, but what I get is s follows.

Graph:
[image: Graph Snapshot]

Any ideas how to place those nasty conf intervals properly? Thank you!

Later edit: in the original data for a given drug I have many rows each containing an adverse reaction, the age category and each of these categories has 2 measurements: prr or EBGM and the corresponding confidence interval. This is not reflected in the data simulation.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

The problem is that each of your bars is really multiple bars plotted over each other, because you have more than one row of data for each combination of `reaction`, `strata`, and `measurement`. (You're getting multiple error bars for the same reason.)

You can see this in the code below, where I've changed `geom_histogram` to `geom_bar` and added `alpha=0.3` and `colour="grey40"` to show the multiple overlapping bars. I've also commented out the error bars.

```
ggplot(Data, aes(x=strata, y=value_measurement, fill=measurement, group=measurement)) +
  geom_bar(stat="identity", position="dodge", alpha=0.3, colour="grey40") +
  facet_wrap(~reaction) #+
#   geom_errorbar(aes(x=strata, ymax=upper_CI, ymin=lower_CI), 
#                 position="dodge", stat="identity")
```

[image]

You can fix this by adding another column to your data that adds a grouping category by which you can separate these bars. For example, in the code below we add a new column called `count` that just assigns numbers 1 through n for each row of data within each combination of `reaction` and `strata`. We sort by `measurement` so that each measurement type will be kept together in the `count` sequence.

```
library(dplyr) 

Data = Data %>% group_by(reaction, strata) %>%
  arrange(measurement) %>%
  mutate(count = 1:n())
```

Now plot the data:

```
ggplot(Data, aes(x=strata, y=value_measurement, 
                 fill=measurement, group=count)) +
  geom_bar(stat="identity", position=position_dodge(0.7), width=0.6) +
  facet_wrap(~reaction, ncol=1) +
  geom_errorbar(aes(x=strata, ymax=upper_CI, ymin=lower_CI, group=count), 
                position=position_dodge(0.7), stat="identity", width=0.3)
```

[image]

Now you can see the separate bars, along with their error bars (which are weird, but only because they're fake data).

Comment: "The problem is that each of your bars is really multiple bars plotted over each other, because you have more than one row of data for each combination of reaction, strata, and measurement": That might be only because of the simulated data. In my table I have for each reaction 2 rows: one with prr the other with EBGM. I have melted the data in this manner because I've read the I need to use the long format with ggplot. the original data had as you said a single row for each strata, reaction with one column EBGM, other 2 columns for ci intervals, one prr with 2 other columns corresponding to CI

Comment: Yes, you do need to melt into long format for ggplot (so that you can map EBGM/prr to the fill aesthetic). However, if your real data have only one row for each level of `measurement` then you shouldn't be having the multiple bars/CIs problem.

Comment: you were right; somewhere in the process of converting the data to long format I took a wrong turn and ended up with multiple rows. Thank you for your help